# HTML List with Images - Align horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to align these list items horizontally but I can't find a work-around. Using `display: block;` on the items doesn't work.

```html
<div class="thumnail-image fix">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#image0"><img alt="" src="mygadgeto/sites/default/files/Polyes-01.jpeg"></a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#image1"><img alt="" src="mygadgeto/sites/default/files/Polyes-02.jpeg"></a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#image2"><img alt="" src="mygadgeto/sites/default/files/Polyes-03.jpeg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: add `display: flex` to `ul`.

Comment: "block-level elements begin on new lines" - See [Block-level vs. inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#Block-level_vs._inline).

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-box`

```
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; // optional
}

li{
 flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ul li {display:inline;}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine
ul li {display:inline-block;}

Answer (score -1):

I always have trouble with this, takes a while messing around with it as I always forget what works, maybe this is right though:

```
li {

  display:inline;
  float:left;

}
```

Comment: Your effort is appreciated, but, sorry, "maybe this is right" is not a very good answer to the question. Test your answer first, and if it does work, then you can tell the OP so.

Answer (score -1):

Go to CSS and type:

```
li {
  display: inline;
  }
```

Works perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/84ng7v5x/2/